# Installing unpublished Gmail addon with user outside domain leads to error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace

We've developed a Gmail addon and we are experiencing the following error message:

[image: "Add-ons owned by users outside of your organization may not be installed"]

whenever we try to install it using "Deploy from Manifest" with a user outside of our domain (the domain where the addon was created).

I don't find any documentation on this, is it something specific of a possible configuration of my domain or is it always the case?

- The installation works fine with users within domain or Gmail accounts
- The addon is configured to be NOT available for individual install (only from G Suite admin)
- The addon is currently under review before being published. **We've shown this error message to a Google reviewer who had not seen it before.**

Comment: Are you the admin of the domain? Does this only happen with a specific user? Do you expect this to be fixed once the add-on is published? When you say you showed this, were you contacting G Suite Support?

Comment: @Jescanellas: no I'm not admin of domain. It happens for different users (did not try with admin users). I showed the message / behaviour in a call with G Suite Marketplace app review team during the review of the addon. I don't know exactly what to expect, I'd like to understand if it's a correct behaviour or not..

Comment: I would say this is intended as the add-on is not public yet, but I would wait until then. If the issue persist, I recommend your admin to contact G Suite Support.